# I sent ETH to ETC from coinbase to Bitsane how do I get my coins back?

Tags: cpp-ethereum, ethereum-classic

I sent ETH from coinbase and received confirmation that they were sent, but It looks like I sent it to ETC from on Bitsane how do I get my coins back?

I am very new to this process and very frustrated.  Can any help me get my funds back?

Will bitsane see that its the wrong account and refund coins to Coinbase?

Comment: Hi there. You will need to open a support case with Bitsane to see if they can help - that's your only chance, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to contact their support team:

https://bitsane.com/contact

Technically speaking, it's possible to get your ETH back as an ETC address is a valid ETH address. It is up to Bitsane to support that though as they hold the private keys to that address.